# acquire/release memory order on different processors

Tags: c++, cpu-architecture, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

Below is from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering) describing the memory order. It looks like acquire/relase will do two things here:

- Prevent (some) reordering within a thread
- Make acquire load after release store (Enforce load happens after store)

Is my understanding correct? It also mentions that

> On strongly-ordered systems — x86, SPARC TSO, IBM mainframe, etc. — release-acquire ordering is automatic for the majority of operations.

Does this mean that on such systems, we can always assume that all loads will happen after store for the same atomic variable? (Even without explicitly specifying `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release`)

> **memory_order_acquire and memory_order_release**
>
> memory_order_acquire: A load operation with this memory order performs the acquire operation on the affected memory location: no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load. All writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread (see Release-Acquire ordering below).
>
> memory_order_release: A store operation with this memory order performs the release operation: no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered after this store. All writes in the current thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable (see Release-Acquire ordering below) and writes that carry a dependency into the atomic variable become visible in other threads that consume the same atomic (see Release-Consume ordering below).
>
> **Release-Acquire ordering**
>
> *If an atomic store in thread A is tagged memory_order_release, an atomic load in thread B from the same variable is tagged memory_order_acquire, and the load in thread B reads a value written by the store in thread A, then the store in thread A synchronizes-with the load in thread B.*
>
> All memory writes (including non-atomic and relaxed atomic) that
> happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A,
> become visible side-effects in thread B. That is, once the atomic load
> is completed, thread B is guaranteed to see everything thread A wrote
> to memory. This promise only holds if B actually returns the value
> that A stored, or a value from later in the release sequence.
>
> The synchronization is established only between the threads releasing
> and acquiring the same atomic variable. Other threads can see
> different order of memory accesses than either or both of the
> synchronized threads.
>
> **On strongly-ordered systems — x86, SPARC TSO, IBM mainframe, etc. —
> release-acquire ordering is automatic for the majority of operations.**
> No additional CPU instructions are issued for this synchronization
> mode; only certain compiler optimizations are affected (e.g., the
> compiler is prohibited from moving non-atomic stores past the atomic
> store-release or performing non-atomic loads earlier than the atomic
> load-acquire). On weakly-ordered systems (ARM, Itanium, PowerPC),
> special CPU load or memory fence instructions are used.

Comment: *Even without explicitly specifying memory_order_acquire and memory_order_release*
- No, compile-time reordering is a thing that can happen, like the non-bolded part of the paragraph you quoted describes.  https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/.
It makes it free for the compiler to implement those orderings, except when blocks other optimizations, such as dead-store elimination on a non-atomic variable that's assigned before and after a release store. In practice it will *often* make asm with `relaxed` that's equivalent on x86 to what you'd get with `acq_rel`, though.

Comment: *Make acquire load after release store (Enforce load happens after store)* - No, *if* an acquire load sees a value from a release store, then there's a happens-before between everything earlier in the writer and everything later in the reader.  If not, there isn't.  Even on strongly-ordered ISAs like x86, a load doesn't wait for every possible store that other threads might do in the future.  Maybe that was just awkward phrasing in English of what you meant.  But see https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ - every x86 / SPARC-TSO load and store has those semantics.

Comment: Just to clarify, in my last comment I meant every load / store **in asm** has acquire / release semantics on those ISAs.  In C++, you're programming against the ISO C++ memory model in terms of compile-time reordering and optimization, if you want programs that work reliably with different compilers than what you tested with, as well as on different ISAs.

Comment: @Steve - You might be reading this backwards. On the strongly-ordered systems you get the strong order even when you don't ask for it, because that is what they have to offer. So you cannot get just acquire, you always get acquire *and* release even when only asking for one of them. Not seeing memory fence instructions is not an optimization, as they are build-in and just not separately visible.